# Timeline alignment

Tags: alignment, cv, timeline

I want to split the timeline of my cv into two lines and let the content on the right, be aligned to the first line of the timeline. But somehow the content aligns to the second line of the timeline.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,margin=0.75in,bottom=.5in,top=.5in}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Custom sectioning with secsty for diffrent sections like praktische erfahrungen oder prasix etc... 
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{%                        
    \LARGE % make sections smaller
    \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{1pt} % insert a thin rule
}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
%% MACROS %%
% size of the boxes used to align text
\newlength{\spacebox}
\settowidth{\spacebox}{123456789}

% vertical space separator between entries
\newcommand{\sepspace}{\vspace*{1em}}

% name macro:
\newcommand{\name}[1]{
\Huge % font size
% print name centered and bold
\begin{center} \textbf{#1} \end{center}\par
}

% header macro:
\newcommand{\header}[1]{
  \large % font size
% print header centered and slanted
  \begin{center} \textsl{#1}\end{center}\par
}

  % skill macro
\newcommand{\skill}[2]{
% set specific indentation for personal information
\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0
% create a box to align two pieces of text
\parbox{3\spacebox}{% three times larger box
\textsc{#1}} % small caps entry name
#2 \par} % entry value
% language level
\newcommand{\lan}[2]{
    % set specific indentation for personal information
    \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0
    % create a box to align two pieces of text
    \parbox{\spacebox}{%
        \textbf{#1}} % bold font entry name
     #2 \par}    % entry value
     


% work experience macro:
\newcommand{\work}[4]{
% name of the work
  \noindent  \textbf{#1}
% at the right the duration
  \hfill 
\framebox{% duration inside a frame box
  \parbox{6em}{%
  \centering\textbf{#2}}} \par
% new paragraph with the school in italics
  \noindent \textit{#3} \par
% description with no hanging and in smaller text
  \vspace*{0.5em}
  \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \small #4 
%back to normal size
\normalsize \par}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

%header
\name{Harjot Singh Maan}
\vspace*{-20pt}
\header{Duales Studium der Wirtschaftsinformatik}
\vspace*{-20pt}
\header{12334444322 & \href{mailto: test@gmail.com}{test@gmail.com}}
\vspace*{-25pt}
\header{Muster-Straße 2, 121223 Musterhausen}

%bildung
\section*{Ausbildung}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}

\noindent {2014 - \\Heute&&& {\bf Musterschule}, {MSS12}\\[5pt]}
\begin{itemize}
\setlength{\itemindent}{70pt}
\vspace*{-15pt}
\item Leistungskurse: XXX
\vspace*{-5pt}
\item Bestrebt das Abitur in 2023
\vspace*{-5pt}
\item Aktueller Notenschnitt: XXX
\vspace*{-5pt}
\item Bestrebt das MINT-EC-Zertifikat 
\end{itemize}
\end{tabular}

%Ausserschulische Aktivitäten
\section*{Außerschulische Aktivitäten}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
\noindent{2023 &&& {\bf Facharbeit}}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This is the timeline:

```
\noindent {2014 - \\Heute&&& {\bf Musterschule}, {MSS12}\\[5pt]}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Adding a screenshot to your question might be helpful to see what you mean.

Comment: When I try to run that code, first I get an error because of the unescaped `&` inside `\header` (should presumably be `\&`). When I fix that, it tells me `\VRule` is undefined. You're using some packages or additional settings not included in this code, without which we can't replicate your issue.